# Highlight most recent date from a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the below table, and I am trying to find a way to add a 'highlight' class to the cell (class="dateRow") with the most recent date/time. 
In this case it would be fourth one, whose date is '2013-05-30'.

I have tried various options but can't quite seem to make it work. Could someone please show me the way, as I have been trying to figure this out, and can't quite seem to get it to work.

```
<table>
    <tr class="topRow"> 
        <td>Yes</td>    
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-23 13:53:20</td>    
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-21 13:53:21</td>    
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-29 13:53:22</td>    
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-30 13:53:23</td>    
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-29 13:53:24</td>    
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-28 13:53:19</td>    
        <td>Some Text</td>  
        <td class="dateRow">2013-05-27 13:53:18</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The most recent JS I tried to adapt was as follows:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function()
    { 
        $('.thisRow').each(function() {
            var $tds = $(this).children('td'),
                max = null,
                maxIndex = null;

        $tds.each(function() {
            var value = +$(this).text().substr(1);
            if(isNaN(value)) {
             if(!max || value > max) {
                 max = value;
                maxIndex = $(this).index();
             }
        }
        });
    if(maxIndex !== null) {
        $tds.eq(maxIndex).addClass('highlight');
    }
});
    }
);
</script>
```

I figure it is the NaN that needed to be adapted, as this did at least highlight a cell, albeit the last one.

Comment: `I have tried various options` which options are those? Show us some code!

Comment: Sorry, I had tried various things most of which failed miserably. I have added the most recent one now, which partially worked (it did at least highlight a cel). I figure it is the NaN that needs changing to something else, but couldn't see what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tag this question as jQuery, but you show some jQuery code, so I'm assuming jQuery is acceptable.

Keep track of your max values as you loop through all dates. The trick is converting your date format to an acceptable javascript date format:

```
$(function () {
    //keep track of max values
    var maxCell = undefined;
    var maxVal = undefined;

    $('.dateRow').each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        var dt = new Date(that.text().replace(' ', 'T')); //convert to js date
        if (!maxCell || dt > maxVal) {
            //update max values
            maxCell = that;
            maxVal = dt;
        }
    });
    maxCell.addClass('highlight'); //highlight cell with max value
});
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWHAr/)**

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it now highlights the first cell "2013-05-23 13:53:20", not the most recent?

Comment: @IGGt Ah... sorry I used `.val()` when I should have used `.text()`... updated my answer and provided working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your code but the **date format**. Please change it to:

```
<tr class="topRow"> 
    <td>Yes</td>    
    <td class="dateRow">2013/05/23 13:53:20</td>    
    <td class="dateRow">2013/05/21 13:53:21</td>    
    <td class="dateRow">2013/05/29 13:53:22</td>    
    ...
```

The above format works almost in all the browsers. For more information, please refer these links:

- [Simplified](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)
- [Javascript Date.parse browser compatibility issue](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.in/2010/11/javascript-dateparse-browser.html)

Comment: that's interesting, as I was taking my dates straight out of MySQL, so didn't think that maybe the date format would be incorrect. very useful to know.